# How to use a pointer or return value to send a function back to main?

Tags: c

I'm working on a mortgage calculator project. I've finished it up for the most part, but the only issue i'm having now is I can't figure out how to point my defined functions back to main, or return them there. For example:

```
double Ammortization(double IM, double loanAmount, double M, int n) {
    

    printf("\nMonth     Old           Monthly           Principal         Interest        New\n");
    printf("        Balance         Payment             Paid              Paid        Balance\n\n");
    double totalPaid = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    double x = IM * loanAmount;
    double princPaid = M - x;
    double intPaid = M - princPaid;
    double newBal = loanAmount - M;
  
    if (newBal < 0) {
      newBal = 0;
    }
    if (i ==1) {
      printf("%3d %11.2lf%15.2lf %18.2lf%18.2lf%15.2lf\n", i, loanAmount, M, princPaid, intPaid, newBal);
    } else if (i > 1 && i <10) {
        printf("%3d %11.2lf%15.2lf %18.2lf%18.2lf%15.2lf\n", i, loanAmount, M, princPaid, intPaid, newBal);
    } else if (i >= 10 && i < 100) {
        printf("%3d %11.2lf%15.2lf %18.2lf%18.2lf%15.2lf\n", i, loanAmount, M, princPaid, intPaid, newBal);
    } else {
        printf("%3d %11.2lf%15.2lf %18.2lf%18.2lf%15.2lf\n", i, loanAmount, M, princPaid, intPaid, newBal);
    }
    printf("\n");
    loanAmount = (loanAmount + x) - M;
    totalPaid = totalPaid +intPaid + princPaid;
  } printf("\nTotal amount paid: %.2lf", totalPaid);
  
  //Not sure what to return here or how to point it back to main.
}
```

In main, this is how I call it to main and it works fine, but I need a return value still or a pointer:

```
  z = Ammortization(IM, loanAmount, M, n);
```

Comment: Your code execution continues from where you called functions. If you want it to be main, call the function inside main if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Is it not just `return totalPaid;` ?

Comment: A `return` statement causes the current function to stop execution, with control returning to the statement following the corresponding function call.  Such a statement is optional in a function that does not return anything -- control also returns when execution reaches the end of the function body -- but it is mandatory in a function, such as yours, that returns a value, because in that case the return statement specifies the return value.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Simply return the value you want `z` to have.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Re “control returning to the statement following the corresponding function call”: That would be very bad news for the OP because then `z = Ammortization(IM, loanAmount, M, n);` would return to the following statement and not complete the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the function to return anything, declare it as returning void instead of double.

If you do need the function to return a double, add a return statement including the actual value to return where you want to leave your function.

-- removed the commenting of the comment to focus on the actual answer

Comment: “Statement” has a particular meaning in C, defined in C 2018 6.8. `z = Ammortization(IM, loanAmount, M, n);` is an expression statement. The parts of it are not statements. “Assigning its value afterwards” is not the next statement. Also, answers are inappropriate places to discuss comments.

Comment: I totally agree with you, that an answer is not the right place to discuss comments. But it served its purpose to start the conversation with you (since I can't comment on other posts with this account yet, unfortunately). Despite the fact that you are probably correct in your reference to the nomenclature definition, we both understood what @John Bollinger meant by his comment. In my "naive everyday nomenclature" the so called "expression statement" refers to my "instruction" and an "expression" may refers to my single "statement". But thanks for the reference. One never stops learning.